# 2D array with any length

Tags: c, arrays, reference, multidimensional-array

```
int func(int arr[100][150], int rows, int columns);
int func(int arr[100][150], int rows, int columns)
{
   //stuff here
}
```

This function works. What should I do if I would like to assign arr size to arr[rows][columns], but not 100 and 150 all the time? If I assign it to 100 and 150 it probably uses more memory than it should if rows and colums are smaller?

```
int func(int arr[rows][columns], int rows, int columns);
int func(int arr[rows][columns], int rows, int columns)
{
   //stuff here
}
```

or

```
int func(int arr[][], int rows, int columns);
int func(int arr[][], int rows, int columns)
{
   //stuff here
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Your question seems to be a possible duplicate of this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051/passing-multidimensional-arrays-as-function-arguments-in-c

Comment: You can find detail regarding sending 2D array to a function here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652598/2d-array-as-argument-to-function/12653518#12653518

Comment: @jrd: Not a good duplicate, as all of the answers fail to indicate that C supports variable-length arrays in function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the dimensions first:

```
int func(int rows, int columns, int arr[rows][columns])
{
    …
}
```

(Actually, the first dimension may be omitted. Dimensions after the first are needed to compute addresses.)

Comment: @hey This is a `gcc` extension, not a standard ([link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)).

Comment: wow, it actually does work. so it allocates only memory needed?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought a forward decl was a gcc extension, but isn't straight-up params part of C99 ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: This is standard C. It is explicitly shown in C 2011 6.7.5.2 10, “EXAMPLE 4”.

Comment: does it allocate only memory needed?

Comment: @hey: An array parameter in a function declaration does not allocate space. It merely provides a way to access the array passed to the function. The calling function (or some ancestor) would allocate space, and that space could be allocated with a similar variable-length array. Allocation could be automatic (“on the stack”), static, or dynamic (with malloc or something similar).

Comment: I mixed up standard versions. That should be C 1999 6.7.5.2 or C 2011 6.7.6.2. It is paragraph 10, “EXAMPLE 4” in both.

Comment: @hey: no new memory is being allocated; `arr` is being treated as a pointer, not an array type.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881667/how-to-pass-a-method-the-height-and-width-of-a-2d-array-as-parameters/12882457#12882457) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Eric's code works, another way to do it (which I prefer) is to replace the explicit array parameter with a pointer like so:

```
int func(int* x, int rows, int columns)
{
        //...
}
```

In this way, the function could be used for both 1D and 2D arrays. This is just an alternative to the answer Eric gave; either one could be used, depending on personal preference and the specific application.